# Dynamically change SVG color in Angular

Tags: angular

I've drawn several circles using svg in Angular as follows:

```
<div (window:resize)="onEatableResized($event)">
  <svg id="eater" (click)="onEaterClicked()"
      [@eater_circle_trigger]="eater_clicked ? 'eater_clicked' : 'none'"
      (@eater_circle_trigger.done)="onEaterDone($event)"
      [attr.width]=eater_data.box_size
      [attr.height]=eater_data.box_size>
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" stroke-width="1"
          [attr.r]=eater_data.radius
          [attr.stroke]=eater_data.stroke_color
          [attr.fill]=eater_data.fill_color>
        </circle>
  </svg>

  <svg *ngFor="let ncircles of total_circles|times; index as id"
    id="{{ 'eatable_' + id }}"
    [attr.width]=eatable_data.box_size
    [attr.height]=eatable_data.box_size>
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" stroke-width="1"
        [@eater_trigger]="dead ? 'dead' : 'alive'"
        [attr.r]=eatable_data.radius
        [attr.stroke]=eatable_data.stroke_color
        [attr.fill]=eatable_data.fill_color
      />
    </svg>
</div>
```

They look like as follows:

[image]

When the svg with id `eater` is clicked (the red circle), it moves on to the next circle by animation:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-eatable",
  templateUrl: "./eatable.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./eatable.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger('eater_circle_trigger', [
      state('eater_clicked', style({
        transform: 'translate(35px, 0px)'
      })),
      transition('* => eater_clicked', [
        animate('1s ease-in-out')
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('eater_trigger', [
      state('dead', style({
        fill: 'while'
      })),
    ])
  ]
})
```

When the animation completes, I want the circle's color to change to white from black using `eater_trigger` on which the `eater` circle moves. But after animation completes, the color doesn't change. Here is the callback `onEaterDone`:

```
onEaterDone(event)
  {
    this.current_eatable++;
    this.dead = true;
    console.log(event.fromeState + " => " + event.toState);
    if (this.current_eatable == this.total_circles)
    {
      console.log('done');
    }
    else
    {
      
    }
  }
```

Output:

[image]

How to make that circle color to white? I'm new to Angular so a details explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to move the red circle to the right on each click?

Comment: @yurzui: No, I want it to move automatically on each black circle after first click. But that's a different problem.

Comment: Do you understand that your `dead` animation will be applied to all your black circles?

Comment: @yurzui: Yes! Unfortunate. But I've found the solution. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter states in your `onEaterDone` callback since it's called for each state and sets `done` property immediately and Angular **can't detect changes on click**.

```
onEaterDone(event) {
  if (event.toState === 'none') {
    return;
  }
```

Then, I wouldn't use `done` property at all since the animation would be applied to all black circles at once. You already have `current_eatable` counter, so why not to use it in your animation condition?

```
[@eater_trigger]="id < current_eatable ? 'dead' : 'alive'"
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/nKvlQn6R9cRSZPwV09ns)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For unknown reason it works in your linked example, but not in my workspace. :( Checking...

Comment: I am able to make it work after copy pasting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Looks like I can use a function to set attribute:

```
<svg *ngFor="let ncircles of total_circles|times; index as id"
    id="{{ 'eatable_' + id }}"
    [attr.width]=eatable_data.box_size
    [attr.height]=eatable_data.box_size>
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" stroke-width="1"
        [attr.r]=eatable_data.radius
        [attr.stroke]=eatable_data.stroke_color
        [attr.fill]="eatableFillColor(id)"
      />
</svg>
```

In the component:

```
eatableFillColor(id)
{
  if (some_condition)
  {
    return "white";
  }
  return "black";
}
```

Comment: @yurzui: What do you suggest?

Comment: Sure, I've added my answer